# Populating a table type in a procedure

Tags: sql, hana

**Environment: HANA 2.0 SPS 03**

My requirement is to create a procedure which iterates through a cursor, do some processing and returns a set of records. Since the processing logic is little complicated and involves comparing a sequence of previous records, I am not able to do this directly using a query.

Since I need to return a set of records, my understanding was to create a table type and while iterating through the cursor I can populate it when needed. But I couldn't find the syntax to do it. I do not want to directly feed cursor(query) response into the table type variable.

*I know I cant do the below, but is there anything equivalent to this?*

```
DECLARE employee_var EMPLOYEE_TYPE;
insert into employee_var values("Naruto");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use a **function**, not a procedure. How? See an example (works in Oracle; sorry if I missed the point, but PL/SQL tag lead me to a conclusion that it *might* help):

Types first:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_emp is object
  2    (empno    number,
  3     ename    varchar2(20),
  4     sal      number
  5    );
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type tt_emp is
  2    table of t_emp;
  3  /

Type created.
```

A function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_emp (par_deptno in number)
  2    return tt_emp
  3  is
  4    v_emp  tt_emp := tt_emp();
  5  begin
  6    select t_emp(empno, ename, sal)
  7      bulk collect into v_emp
  8      from emp
  9      where deptno = par_deptno;
 10
 11    return v_emp;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.
```

How to use it:

```
SQL> select * from table(f_emp(10));

     EMPNO ENAME                       SAL
---------- -------------------- ----------
      7782 CLARK                      2450
      7839 KING                       5000
      7934 MILLER                     1300

SQL>
```

Comment: Even in Hana if I need to directly fetch from a table, it is possible but I have to iterate and process the data. In terms of other programming language, I am trying to query the db, iterate the response in a FOR loop and push it to an array or a hash or an object.

Comment: Right; it doesn't really matter. My example is a simple one. You'd - if you have to - use a loop, do some processing, and - at the end - store the result. The principle is the same, technique might be different.

Comment: You are right. But store the result? where? thats the problem with Hana, I was not able to find an object equivalent as you have mentioned in Oracle.

Comment: I see ... unfortunately, I wouldn't know whether it is possible and - if so - how to do it. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

Although it's worst performance version, maybe it can be optimised. Anyway here is a snippet (code is not tested):

```sql
PROCEDURE "USP_CalcRowSet" (
           OUT tmpTab TABLE(
                        Col1 INTEGER,
                        Col2 INTEGER
                    )
        )
        LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
        SQL SECURITY INVOKER
        AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE CURSOR cursorSample FOR select value1, value2 from dbo.table1 where 1=1;
    DECLARE calcVar INTEGER;
    DECLARE prevVal INTEGER;

    FOR vRow as cursorSample DO
        --processing
        calcVar := exp(coalesce(vRow.value2, prevVal, 1));
        prevVal := calcVar;
        INSERT INTO tmpTab VALUES (vRow.value1, calcVar);
    END FOR;
END;
```

---

Rahul.

Since procedure processing using a cursor is resource-intensive operation, i would recommend you to examine **window functions** method for your case.

Here is an example of processing previous 3 values above current row, while moving through ID window.

```sql
select
    ID
    ,VAL
    ,lag(VAL,1) over (partition by ID order by DTTM) as PREV_VAL1
    ,lag(VAL,2) over (partition by ID order by DTTM) as PREV_VAL2
    ,lag(VAL,3) over (partition by ID order by DTTM) as PREV_VAL3
    ,lag(VAL,1) over (partition by ID order by DTTM) / lag(VAL,2) over (partition by ID order by DTTM) as CALC_V1_2_V2
    ,DTTM
from
(
select 'A' as ID, 101 as VAL, convert(date, getdate()+1) as DTTM 
union all
select 'A' as ID, 102 as VAL, convert(date, getdate()+2) as DTTM 
union all
select 'A' as ID, 103 as VAL, convert(date, getdate()+3) as DTTM 
union all
select 'A' as ID, 104 as VAL, convert(date, getdate()+4) as DTTM 
union all
select 'B' as ID, 201 as VAL, convert(date, getdate()+1) as DTTM 
union all
select 'B' as ID, 301 as VAL, convert(date, getdate()+2) as DTTM 
union all
select 'B' as ID, 401 as VAL, convert(date, getdate()+3) as DTTM 
union all
select 'B' as ID, 501 as VAL, convert(date, getdate()+4) as DTTM 
) v1
```

You can also use more complex window operators, like unbounded/preceding following window scale around your value group, which are described here, if you use SAP HANA WH
 engine:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20a353327519101495dfd0a87060a0d3.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have been using window function but the problem is I do not know the depth. So the functionality is if the value is null, I have take the previous non null value for that column and the same id which sometimes go to thousands of records.

Comment: Ok, i get it. If so, i think you were on right direction: create procedure that returns table as OUT parameter, populated with processed data.

Comment: Thats my question, how do I populate a table type with data that is not directly from a query.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't access any SAP HANA environment to test the code, i only can guess how it would look like. Added to UPD in my answer.